# setTimeout seems to be starting too soon -- on $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a table that when a cell has focus it gives me it's location in two variables. (see code below). I need to reset that location on a `blur` event, but keep the first data long enough to `click` a button.

I've tried a `setTimeout`, but it seems to be starting on dom ready.

Fairly new to javascript, so any help is appreciated.

```
$("td input").focus(function() { // Finds current row and column number
  columnNumber = $(this).parent().index();
  rowNumber = $(this).parent().parent().index();
})

$("td input").blur(function(){ // Delayed -- cancels current row and column number on blur
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  var myTimer = setTimeout(function(){ columnNumber = -1; rowNumber = -1;
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Bunch of things. First, you're mixing `setTimeout` and `clearInterval`; you should use `clearTimeout`. Second, you're making a new local variable `myTimer` every time that `blur` callback is invoked. You'll never have a previously set timer to clear with `clearTimeout`, since that variable goes out of scope and its value is lost every the function is called. If you want to hold onto the value returned by the previous invocation of `setTimeout`, you need to move `var myTimer` outside the function...

Comment: Finally, it's really impossible to tell what you mean, "starts on DOM ready". The DOM-ready event only happens once, and it will happen before you have a chance to bind or invoke either your focus or blur callbacks, so there's no way either of these are being invoked "on DOM-ready". What's the *symptom*? Is the value of `columnNumber`/`rowNumber` simply not being reset to `-1`?

Comment: Why do you even need the `.focus()` handler?  Why not just fetch the `rowNumber` and `columnNumber` in the `.blur()` handler?  What are you ever doing with the `columnNumber` and `rowNumber` because your current code doesn't actually ever change anything except a couple variables.